# Wait until a variable is initialized in Cypress

Tags: javascript, variables, cypress, wait, chaining

How could I wait until a variable is initialized in Cypress?

E.g. I have the following code:

```
let width;
cy.get("[data-cy=foo-bar]")
  .should(element => (width = element.width()))
  .get("[data-cy=baz-baz]")
  //some other chained Cypress operations
  ...;
```

I would like the line `.getCy("baz-baz")` no to execute until the `width` was set. How could I achieve that in the cleanest way you know?

I would like to preserve the chaining of operations and avoid nesting, since I may require more than one variable later on and it becomes quite messy to put everything inside the `should`.

Comment: What about wait-until  ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until.  So the code be like  :  cy.get("[data-cy=foo-bar]")
  .waitUntil(element => (width = element.width()))

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do or avoid with your code. Are you checking to see if `foo-bar` renders in your app?

Comment: @jjhelguero, there is a horizontal scrolling present in my app. I am trying to find out the width of the scrollable area and move that width to the right (i.e. go one page to the right). But the width is still not initialized before I try to call the `scrollTo`. But the question is more general, because I remember having some other cases when I had to wait for the should to complete before continuing the processing and did not know how to do that. I do not want to nest my code inside the `should`, since it will lead to a hard to read code when I will have more than one `should`, and I will.

Comment: @AnkurGupta, can I continue chaining after the `waitUntil` and be sure that when the chained operation is called the `waitUntil` was complete? The whole point of using the cypress is the ability to chain to have maintainable and readable code.

Comment: Hi @manymanymore , I am not very much sure about its capability of chained operations. Can you make a try and update here

Comment: @AnkurGupta, in other words, value of what type does the `waitUntil` return?

Comment: Hi @manymanymore . Please have a look https://npm.runkit.com/cypress-wait-until . You will find all answers of your questions